# WPF LINQ query result as percentage

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm

How can I concatenate the '**%**' symbol at the end of a query result? I know how to do it in SQL but I have no idea how to do it with linq. The result that I am getting now is 83. How can I make it 83%?

```
private void SetLaborStandard()
{
    int.TryParse(MDate.ToString("MM"), out int month);
    LaborStandard = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(db.KPIs.Where(a => a.sMonth == month).Select(a => a.LaborStandard*100).FirstOrDefault()), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

Comment: what is the data type of `LaborStandard `?

Comment: It's a decimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have marked this post with WPF and MVVM, I thought I'd share with you that this kind of formatting can be handled directly by XAML. You do not need to append % sign with the value. Just expose your property as standard `Decimal` type and bind your UI control (`TextBlock`, `Label` or whatever) to this property. Within your binding, you should use `StringFormat` to specify that this value should be formatted as percentage like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LaborStandard, StringFormat={}{0}%}" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!